# cannot set headers after they are sent to the client when i use mongoose remove function

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, header, populate

when i use this code

```
activecode.remove(err => {
                        return res.status(500).json("error message ")
                    });
```

get the error cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

when i remove the above code it works without error

this is my code

```
 async activeUser(req, res, next) {

        try {
            const code = req.params.code;
            const activecode = await ActiveCode.findOne({
                code
            }).gt("expire", new Date()).populate("user").limit(1).exec();

            if (activecode) {

                if (activecode.used) {
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        message: "از این لینک قبلا استفاده شده است"
                    })
                } else {
                    activecode.used = true;
                    activecode.save(err => {
                        if (err) {
                            return res.status(500).json({
                                message: "خطایی در فعال سازی رخ داد"
                            })
                        };
                    });
                    if (activecode.user) {
                        activecode.user.isActive = true;
                        activecode.user.save(err => {
                            if (err) {
                                return res.status(500).json({
                                    message: "خطایی در فعال سازی رخ داد"
                                })
                            };
                        });
                        const user = {
                            id: activecode.user.id,
                            name: activecode.user.name,
                            email: activecode.user.email,
                            isActive: activecode.user.isActive
                        }
                        activecode.remove(err => {
                            return res.status(500).json("خطایی در فعال سازی اکانت رخ داد ")
                        });
                        return res.status(200).json({
                            user
                        });
                    }
                }
            } else {

                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: "چنین لینکی برای فعال سازی حساب وجود ندارد"
                });
            }
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: "خطایی در فعال سازی حساب رخ داده لطفا دوباره امتحان کنید"
            });
        }
    }
```

any 
`res.status.json`
used with return 
what i do for solve this problem . where my code trying to send multiple responses

Comment: Basically this error means that the response has been already sent, and  the code is trying to sent it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you already have an async function with `try/catch` so you don't need to use `.save()` and `.remove()` with callback. You just need to use `await` and let the `catch` handle error for you.

This may help:

```
async activeUser(req, res, next) {

    try {
        const code = req.params.code;
        const activecode = await ActiveCode.findOne({
            code
        }).gt("expire", new Date()).populate("user").limit(1).exec();

        if (activecode) {

            if (activecode.used) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: "از این لینک قبلا استفاده شده است"
                })
            } else {
                activecode.used = true;
                await activecode.save();
                if (activecode.user) {
                    activecode.user.isActive = true;
                    await activecode.user.save();
                    const user = {
                        id: activecode.user.id,
                        name: activecode.user.name,
                        email: activecode.user.email,
                        isActive: activecode.user.isActive
                    }
                    await activecode.remove();
                    return res.status(200).json({
                        user
                    });
                }
            }
        } else {

            return res.status(400).json({
                message: "چنین لینکی برای فعال سازی حساب وجود ندارد"
            });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: "خطایی در فعال سازی حساب رخ داده لطفا دوباره امتحان کنید"
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of your code:

```
activecode.remove(err => {
    return res.status(500).json("خطایی در فعال سازی اکانت رخ داد ")
});
return res.status(200).json({
    user
});
```

With

```
activecode.remove((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
         return res.status(500).json("خطایی در فعال سازی اکانت رخ داد ");
    } else {
         return res.status(200).json({user});
    }
});
```

The problem here your request tries to send response twice, which is not allowed.

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The situation is arising because you are trying to send the response for a particular request twice which is not allowed.

Also on side note,your request route doesnt gets finished when they encouter a response(res.status().json() or res.send()) it will continue to the parse to the end of the function and if while parsing they encounter another res.send() or res.status().json() they will throw the above error.

for example

```html
app.get('/some_route',(req,res)=>{
  if("condition")
    res.send('something);
  else
    res.send('another thing');
})


app.get('/some_route',(req,res)=>{
  if("condition")
    res.send('something');
  res.send("another something");
})
```

the first example is correct but the second one is not

Comment: I change the remove part of code to return the res but still I have same error